# Redirect query string url to non query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to redirect /cgibin/webdata_pro.pl?_cgifunction=form&_layout=jobs.pl

to

http://compliancesearch.com/compliance_jobs.html

there is usually a query string after jobs.pl.I've tried a bunch of things including:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewwriteRule /cgibin/webdata_pro.pl?_cgifunction=form&_layout=jobs.pl(.*) http://compliancesearch.com/compliance_jobs.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a RewriteRule. You need to use the %{QUERY_STRING} variable.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _cgifunction=form&_layout=jobs.pl
RewriteRule ^cgibin/webdata_pro.pl http://compliancesearch.com/compliance_jobs.html? [R=301,L]
```

The better place to do this, however, is probably in the `webdata_pro.pl` script.